# Saving an HTML node/param from web browser as a string

Tags: c#, html, c#-4.0

I apologize in advance for my bad terminology, I am very new to C# and coding in general.

I want to scan through the html of my web browser (webBrowser1) and find the value of a certain parameter/node. I know how to use getElementById although that doesn't work in this case.

The section of HTML I will need to scan is here:

```
<body>
   <div id="wrap">
       <div id="main" role ="main" class="...">
           <div style="width:100%; margin...">
               <applet code="...">
                   <param name="lotsOfParamsHere" value="...">
                   <param name="server" value="myString1">
                   <param name="port" value="myString2">
                   <param name="mppass" value="myString3">
               </applet>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to save the values of server, port and mppass, as strings in my program. I have looked at the HTMLAgilityPack and the usual methods but I am not very good at getting data from HTML at all. Any help would be much much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var dict = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("param")
    .ToDictionary(n=>n.Attributes["name"].Value,n=>n.Attributes["value"].Value);
```

Now you can use it as

```
var port = dict["port"];
```

---

or without HtmlAgilityPack, you can get it directly from webbrowser control

```
var dict = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("param")
          .Cast<HtmlElement>()
          .ToDictionary(p => p.GetAttribute("name"), p => p.GetAttribute("value"));
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for this, you don't know how much I appreciate it ! :)

Answer (score 0):

to obtain the value...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

alert($('#wrap param[name=server]').val());

});
```

Comment: I don't see any `Javascript` tag in the question